# Get PayPal transaction fee without using IPN?

Tags: paypal, ci-merchant

First of all I know there seems to be a few related questions about this which I have read but I can't find a definitive answer to my query. I hope its OK posting this here.

Related: [receive more response data in ci-merchant library codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434555/receive-more-response-data-in-ci-merchant-library-codeigniter)

Related: [How do I get the information returned in the IPN after a transaction in PayPal using ci_merchant library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249355/how-do-i-get-the-information-returned-in-the-ipn-after-a-transaction-in-paypal-u)

I basically want to get what the paypal IPN returns with CI Merchant.

Now I am calling purchase_return() which is great and returns something like this:

```
Merchant_paypal_api_response Object
(
    [_status:protected] => complete
    [_message:protected] => 
    [_reference:protected] => XXXXX
    [_data:protected] => 
    [_redirect_url:protected] => 
    [_redirect_method:protected] => GET
    [_redirect_message:protected] => 
    [_redirect_data:protected] => 
)
```

And I know that CI Merchant doesn't actually have a GetExpressCheckoutDetails call which would contain more details about the transaction.

But according to here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/ that call wouldn't return anything to do with **mc_fee** or **payment_fee** anyway?

So I am simply asking is this at all possible to get the same sort of data that the paypal IPN returns without actually using it obviously.

Seems a bit backward to have to call the paypal IPN as well just to get additional details like **mc_fee** or **payment_fee** when I am already using the CI Merchant API method which is supposed to eliminate having to use the IPN? I can't believe the API doesn't return this sort of info.

Am I being completely mental here and missed the obvious? I just want to get the paypal fee for that transaction so I can do some accounting my end.

Is this possible?

Hope someone can shed some light.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are right, CI-merchant doesn't support the `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` method, and that method doesn't actually return the fee.

You might have more luck looking into calling the PayPal [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) method, which seems to return the fee. You would need to alter CI-merchant to add this functionality, or just call it separately though.